# What is the successful path to writing hard-core javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, testing, architecture

I've always been dabbling in javascript, but never really got hugely into writing a lot of javascript until last year or so. One thing I noticed is that my javascript started to grow so complex, that parts of it were more complex than the server's application code (minus all the framework code of course, such as Spring or Hibernate).

This caused me to realize that if you want to write a complex javascript application, in the same way you've been writing complex web applications on the server, you have to start thinking about best practices, architecture, how you structure your files, how you test your code, what abstractions do you use to create smaller, more reusable components, what is the best way to pass parameters and send messages, should i pass parameters or object literals, and just best practices all around. None of this provided or encouraged by Javascript itself, and everyone seems to have its own way of going about everything.

And of course, because Javascript offers such very poor api out of the box, I often spend a countless amount of time researching what the best tools for the job are. Facilities like importing files and dependencies, or even a basic collection library, are things NOT handled by the language. Let's not forget that IDE support, even in something like Idea 10.5, is actually pretty bad and nowhere near as rich as say Java due to its dynamic nature and the lack of these hard-bindings for packages and imports.

Outside of jquery, which I really like and feel comfortable with, I still haven't made any decisions as to the "right" way to do things either. This is odd to me.

Everyone seems to have their own coding idioms too - they either write in a pure functional style, or they try and create a whole classical programming model and then use that. People's coding standards and idioms vary from library to library and person to person. All of this makes knowing what the "right" thing to do an incredible task.

Even worse, there doesn't seem to be books on this sort of thing. It's like nobody has bothered to tackle it - which is totally contrary to what we have in the Java space, or many other spaces for that matter.

What is the right/successful path to having a refined way to successfully write nice-looking and robust javascript for complex web applications?

Comment: First tip: Java != Javascript.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Well, of course, but that doesn't mean we should just hack it.

Comment: javascript tends to be used for sticky tape programming. Perhaps its about time to make it more mature and structured, but I think most developer like its more dynamic and open development.

Comment: There is no book about this? I thought 'JavaScript the Good Parts' is just that? Haven't read it yet though.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: This book is basically "how to make javascript not suck". It really doesn't tackle larger application issues at all. It's a very good book - I've read it - but it doesn't even begin to show you how to build large-scale applications with javascript. The book is about details, not the big picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like my knowledge of Javascript expanded and became more complete after reading Douglas Crockford's [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742).  He really clarifies the most difficult and important parts of the language.

Reading it made clear the different types of inheritance: neoclassical, functional, prototypal.  And the different ways to invoke a function: constructor invocation, apply invocation, function invocation, and method invocation.

I would start there.

Comment: I've read this book. This is all low-level stuff. I'm talking about big-picture concepts for building actual applications, not just how to properly iterate over an array.

Comment: Oh you're thinking more architectural-level.  You might take a look at Jon Resig's book.